# Can i host angular app on one port and legacy app on another (in a vm)

Tags: angular, apache, iframe, vagrant, portforwarding

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to ask this question correctly so forgive (or advise me) if i'm doing this wrong.

Here is the scenario.

I have an angular 4 app where the files exist on my host operating system (ubuntu 16.04) and I serve the file using the npm start command.  As I understand it (I didn't write the app) when I run npm start it runs this command which is located in my package.json:

```
ng serve --sourcemap --extract-css --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

Somehow this results in the site being view able at localhost:4200

I have another legacy php5 style application which is on virtual machine (also ubuntu 16.04).  The virtual machine is managed with Vagrant and is running from Virtualbox.  I have the host file on my host machine set up as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.11   my.site
```

The virtual machine has apache2 running and is all configured.  Right now I can have both systems up and running simultaneously with no problem, however I have been asked to put parts of the old legacy system into the new app by way of an iframe.  Technically, this works, however because both systems have a different domain I am very limited as to what I can do with the old system that is iframed into the new one.  For example I can't even change basic CSS (which is pretty much all I need to do) because of the security issues around iframes.

My question is,  Is there a way where I can have both systems up and running under the same IP or domain name and have one inside of the other in an iframe in a way where the security issue is eliminnated?

So, for example, I might have localhost:4200 be the new angular app hosted on the host machine and inside of that have localhost:80 point to the site on the virtual machine.

This question involves a few different things.

1) Can i forword traffic from one port to a virtual machine and from another port (on the same IP) to the local machine?

2) Even if i can do this.  Will the rules of iframes allow me to control content within an iframe if the domain/IP is the same but the ports are different?

Or...  If there is a much better way to do this, I'm willing to hear that as well.

Addendum:

Not sure if this matters, but there is also a proxy.config.json file located in the angular app which looks like this:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8001",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

This is used so that my api requests can be sent to yet another port on the host machine where an api is running.  That api is running from a local lumen codebase.  I suspect this has no bearing on my core issue but because the ng serve command includes it I wanted this here for clarity.

Comment: Well I think I've answered one of my questions already.  That is the question of would this even work if I could set it up correctly.  The answer appears to be no.  According to the 'Same Origin Policy' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy the port needs to match as well not just the domain.

Comment: I am now leaning towards some sort of reverse proxy to solve my issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a better way to do this that doesn't involve some complicated reverse proxy.  The answer was pretty simple actually.

The answer came when someone asked me how we go about deploying an angular app to production and I had no idea how this is actually done.  In our development phase we were simply serving the app using the npm start command but as it turns out there is also a command called 'ng build --prod' which is used when you want to deploy to production.

Up until this point it always confused me why a front end application would need to be served in any special way.  Why couldn't I just put the files on a box and then point apache to them?  Turns out, you can do exactly this.  The ng build command makes your angular app into a simple set of files that you can put wherever you want to host, so for me, I just put those files right on the vm that hosts the old system (I moved the old system to sub-folder) and wholla!  No cross origin problems anymore.